# .NET C# DropDownList pass parameter to function

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I don't really know how to word this...I have a drop down list that queries a database and displays a list of descriptions based on ids. I want the user to be able to select a description, push a button and call my getQueryResults() function with the id being passed and not the description. getQueryResults(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) doesn't work because of conflicting types. What else can I use?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataConnector dc = new DataConnector();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dc.getCodeTypes();
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "description";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataConnector dc = new DataConnector();
        GridView2.DataSource = dc.getQueryResults(DropDownList1.SelectedValue); //error: cannot convert from string to int
        GridView2.DataBind();

    }

    public List<CodeDesc> getQueryResults(int searchTerm)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "select id, code, descr from code_desc where code_type_id = :searchTerm";
           //more stuff
```

My manager does not want me to change the query string. (previously I had used "select id, code, descr from code_desc where code_type_id = (select id from code_desc where descr = :searchTerm);" where searchTerm was the string description thus eliminating the need for the id)

Comment: GridView2.DataSource = dc.getQueryResults(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by wrapping your DropDownList DataBinding inside an `IsPostBack` check.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dc.getCodeTypes();
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "description";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

I you do not, every time you load the page the data is bound again and the DropDownList goes back to it's first value.

Then you can call the `getQueryResults` with the `SelectedValue` by converting the value to an `int`.

```
GridView2.DataSource = dc.getQueryResults(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
```

Finally, google [parameratized queries](https://www.google.nl/#q=parameratized+queries+c%23).

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedValue property from the DropDownList class is a string

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[BindableAttribute(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[ThemeableAttribute(false)]
public virtual string SelectedValue { get; set; }
```

An that is why you get this convertion error, you need to parse the string into an int or even better just pass the string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to pass in an int.

```
int parameter = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataConnector dc = new DataConnector();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dc.getCodeTypes();
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "id"
            item.Value = "description";

            DropDownList1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: This should work for this problem. I had a similar problem of getting the ID